# Cannot GET /hotel/register

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mern, mongodb-atlas

`Actually i want to fetch the data from frontend and store it in backend still I'm getting cannot get /hotel/register error  below i'm attaching the codes. Please help me out to find the specific error as i have cross checked it multiple times and still not getting what is the issue

app.js

```
`require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app=express();
require("./db/conn");
const cors=require("cors");
const router = require("./Routes/router")
const hotelRouter = require("./Routes/hotelRouter")
const PORT = 4003;


//middleware
app.use(express.json()); //express.json isliye likha joh bhi data frontend se ayega woh json format mei hoga agar hum yeh nhi likhage toh backend mei undefined show karega
app.use(cors());//cors bridge the gap of frontend n backend ports
app.use(router);
app.use(hotelRouter);


// app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
//     res.status(200).json(`server start`)
// })

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Server start at PORT NO : ${PORT}`)
})`
```

hotelRouter.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();
const hotelrs = require("../controllers/hotelControllers");
const upload = require("../multerconfig/storageConfig")

//Routes 
// router.post("/admin/register",controllers.adminregister);
// router.post("/admin/sendotp",controllers.adminOtpSend);
// router.post("/admin/login",controllers.adminLogin);
router.post("/hotel/register",upload.single("hotel_profile") ,hotelrs.hotelregister);

module.exports = router
```

hotelservice.js

```
import { commonrequest } from "./ApiCall";
import { BACKEND_URL } from "./Helper"



// export const hotelregisterfunc =  async(data) => {
//     return await commonrequest("POST",`${BACKEND_URL}/hotel/register`,data);
//   // return await commonrequest("POST",`${BACKEND_URL}/hotel/register`,data)
// }


export const hotelregisterfunc =  async(data,header) => {
  return await commonrequest("POST",`${BACKEND_URL}/hotel/register`,data,header);
// return await commonrequest("POST",`${BACKEND_URL}/hotel/register`,data)
}
```

hotelschema.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator= require("validator");

const hotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fname:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trime:true,
        },
    location:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        validate(value){
            if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
                throw Error ("not valid email")
            }
        }
    },
    mobile:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        minlength:10,
        maxlength:10
    },
    star:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    room:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    profile:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    datecreated:Date,
    dateUpdated:Date
})


//model -->collection ko define karna
const hotel = new mongoose.model("hotelregisters",hotelSchema);

module.exports = hotel;
```

I tried to rectify my codes but still it is showing cannot get /hotel/register

Comment: `/hotel/register` is a post endpoint, make sure that the request you are sending is a post request and not GET. Maybe check with commonRequest from ApiCall if the request that is being sent is correct or not

Comment: can you please add error block or screenshot for better error understanding.